# Tomcat website is not starting

Tags: java, xml, rest, tomcat

This is my xml file. I want to make web app.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>myApp</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JAVA WS</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
             <param-value>myApp</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JAWA WS</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and this is my java class.

```
package myApp;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/main")
public class Main {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayHello(){
        String response = "<?xml version='1.0'?>" + "<hello>Hello XML</hello>" ;
        return response;
    }
}
```

Any idea why it isn't working? 404 error appears. Can anybody explain me what should i do next, i have Json data which i want to put on the website, what should i do? Pull data from server and then show it as table?

Comment: Why won't you research spring-boot, by far the easiest way to start making new java app. http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/#quick-start and you can go from there...

Comment: 404 error appears when doing what?